# Angular 2 RC5 router.navigate not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following expression if the user is a guest:

```
this.router.navigate(['/intro']);
```

in my app.component.ts `ngOnInit()` method.

My app.component.html has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

but when I access my app as guest, the `IntroComponent` is not displayed and the URL stays empty without the `/intro`.

What's wrong?

my app.routes.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{path:'intro',component: IntroComponent},
{path:'login',component: LoginComponent},
{path:'register', component: RegisterComponent}
];
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?  Do you have the routes configured?  Are you importing them properly (depending on which version you have)?  We'll need more information to help you out

Comment: The routes are configured, RC.5. I added my app.routes.ts, The HomeCOmponent is loaded Although I am navigating with this.router to intro

Comment: Please paste a minimal example into a plunker.

Comment: @TheUnreal : Have you got any solution for this??

Comment: @sachinkulkarni nope I have not used this way

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}, //(redirectTo or component)
{path:'intro',component: IntroComponent},
{path:'login',component: LoginComponent},
{path:'register', component: RegisterComponent}
];
```

the default `pathMatch` strategy is `prefix` in routes so `path: ''` with `prefix` means practically everyroute. So everyroute was navigated to the `HomeComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because initial navigation is not completed when calling `this.router.navigate(['/intro'])` from `ngOnInit`.

There are two ways to solve this:

**Solution #1**

In `app.module.ts` you disable initial navigation

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { initialNavigation: false })
```

Ref: [router.navigate failing silently on OnInit of component](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11748)

**Solution #2**

If you do not want to disable initial navigation then use `setTimeout` to allow the initial navigation to complete.

```
setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['/intro']), 1)
```